# Camel SFTP creates too many connections

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel SFTP. It looks like the connections are getting created on each poll but never closed. Camel v2.19.

Same setting work's fine with SMB.

```
sftp://user@server.com:22/Cdm_extract?delay=90000&include=.*.*&localWorkDirectory=%2Ftmp&password=xxxxxx&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=20000&readLockLoggingLevel=OFF&readLockTimeout=60000"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `disconnect=true` to close the connection after the poll.

Comment: Where this needs to be set in camel route? or application.properties ?

Comment: In the endpoint uri